# How can I remove the default generated <div> tags in view's result?

Tags: views

I am using a views in my drupal web site. I have set 'style' to **'Unformatted'** and 'Row style' to **'Fields'**

Also I have Rewrote the output of the field with my HTML tags.

But I have a problem in the result.
Every row is located inside a [div] tag
for example the first row is located in

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first"></div>
```

How can I setup the view in order to remove this extra [div] tag ?!?!?

I don't need this wrapper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to touch the theme you could use [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) module to strip all the extra div's.

Comment: Does the Drupal 7 version work well?

Comment: @MPD it does on my site :)

Comment: @nathan6137, thanks.  I have been hesitant to use it on a client site b/c there hasn't been activity of the project in a while.

Comment: Semantic Views is not necessary if you are using Views 3.x - the functionality of SV is wrapped into Views core. http://drupal.org/node/740686

Comment: @sheena_d, did all of the SV functioality get folded in?  I thought it was just fields and that you couldn't pick elements for things like how rows in an unformatted list get generated.

Comment: @MPD - you're right, I was remembering wrong. You can assign a class to the row wrapper, but you cannot actually affect it from the Views UI.

Answer (score 9):

The easiest thing to do is copy the template files from "sites/all/modules/views/theme/" into you theme (I normally make a "views/" subdirectory).

If you want to make this change for all themes, edit "views-view-unformatted.tpl.php".

If you want to just change that view, edit the view then click on the **Theme: Information** link.  It will show the template suggestions for the view.  Copy 
If you want to make this change for all themes, copy "views-view-unformatted.tpl.php" to the proper name, and edit that file.

In both cases, make sure you clear the Drupal caches to make sure the system finds the new files.

Answer (score 7):

This solution combines and builds on David Paul's and MDP's solutions and  removes the `<div class="views-row ...">` in a consistent way for all views that are properly configured without additional modules.

### Drupal 7 & 8+

**Step 1:
Disable all class configurations in the *Style options* of the view's *Format* section.**

You must do this for any and all views that you want to remove the wrapper from:

[image: Views Format Style Settings]

### Drupal 7

**Step 2: Copy `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` from the Views module into your theme's `templates` folder**  and modify the logic to ignore the div when classes are empty.

Change the following lines from:

```php
<div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
  <?php print $row; ?>
</div>
```

to:

```php
<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) : ?><div class="<?php print $classes_array[$id]; ?>"><?php endif; ?>
  <?php print $row; ?>
<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) : ?></div><?php endif; ?>
```

### Drupal 8+

**Step 2: Copy `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` from the Views module into your theme's `templates/views/` folder**  and modify the logic to ignore the div when {{row.attributes}} are empty.

Change the following lines from:

```
<div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
  {{ row.content }}
</div>
```

to:

```
{% if default_row_class or row.attributes is not empty %}
<div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
  {{ row.content }}
</div>
{% else %}
  {{ row.content }}
{% endif %}
```

Honestly, I'm not sure why the Views module doesn't do this itself...  its a total WTF and could be a nice improvement for Themer's eXperience.

Comment: THIS is the correct answer

Comment: I've added instructions now for Drupal 8 to this answer.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer in my opinion.

Comment: would be even better if the row-class could be added to the row.content without creating that extra div at all

Comment: Not sure I understand how that would work.  This is literally the only wrapper you get around the views results,  the only other wrappers are at the individual row level.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into the `Theming: Information` section and override one of the styled templates for your view. That's where the stuff happens. Be sure to use the Rescan button when you create an appropriately named tpl file, so that Drupal picks it up.

Answer (score 1):

To remove this in Drupal 7 you can click on the Fields settings and turn off "Provide default wrapper elements"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Drupal 7 then you don't need to play with template files to remove the wrapper divs.  Those wrappers come as part of the output, which suggests they can be controlled in the view, which they can.

Under FORMAT > Show: fields | settings - click settings, then uncheck the wrapper option.  That's it.

Comment: that is not entirely true, even if you uncheck wrapper options, views would not let you remove all divs

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by overriding views-view.tpl.php file. Copy this file from views module into your theme directory and remove the beginning wrapper.
[image]

Also remove the div wrapping the $rows.

[image]