# Get the paragraph fields of a content type in a loop in another page

Tags: paragraphs, 9

I have added a paragraph in content type News.
I want the **fields on this paragraph** in my custom **home page** in a loop.
As The News Contents would be shown in a **carousel** in home page.
I am new to drupal. Can anyone help me?
I have tried using views. the content is rendered. but as the view has extra divs, the design breaks.
**Drupal 9 using twig**.

Using semantics view, i can modify or add classes to the div. but i needed to get rid of the outer two divs i.e. from container and views-view.html.twig. As the carousel is out of the view. and the view is acting like a single carousel entity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove the default generated <div> tags in view's result?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/how-can-i-remove-the-default-generated-div-tags-in-views-result)

Comment: Thanks for the link @PatrickKenny. I installed the module, but could not edit accordingly. So, as i am creating the theme too, i removed the div wrappers from the views-view and container and my problem is solved.

Comment: Then you need to describe what you had trouble editing.  Among the answers on that question, [this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/192311/5147) is probably the most helpful for your case.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for being vague. But i wanted a solution without the views. I.e. getting the values of the custom fields of News Content in a paragraph block or a node. @PatrickKenny

Comment: Ok, you can do this in Views in less than 5 minutes by stripping the tags, but you can also find a way to do it without Views.